# How to not display URI variable on redirect?

Tags: javascript, jquery, redirect, csrf

I have the following form which is used to redirect the user to search a particular date.

```
   <form action="/datesearch/" method="get" id="goto_date_form" style="display:none;">
        <input name="dt" type="text" />
        <input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value="[my csrf token value]">
    </form>
```

When this form is called with `$('#goto_date_form').submit();`, it does redirect the page, but it displays both the value of dt and the value of csrfmiddlewaretoken as URI variables.

i.e. when searching for 2016-07-06 it redirects to

```
`http://localhost:8000/datesearch/?dt=2016-07-06&csrfmiddlewaretoken=[my csrf token value]`
```

How can I get it to stop displaying the csrf token?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply change `method="get"` to `method="post"` (and also back end too)

Answer (score 2):

When you use GET in a form, all the data in the form is placed in the URI.  If you change your form to use POST instead, the data will be put in the request body - not visible in the URI (but still visible to the user if the user decides to view the Request details).

NOTE if you change from GET to POST, you might have to make some changes in your server side code as well, depending on the method you are using to fetch the data.

Answer (score 1):

Use `method="post"` in form tag to prevent data passing in url